# Cause of Action References to Penal Code and Violation of Civil Code in a Complaint Filed in the US

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, civil-procedure

If a complaint contain multiple cause of actions (e.g., one cause of action references to the Penal Code, and another cause of action references to violation of Civil Code), is this a civil or criminal lawsuit, or both in the same complaint? Why?

Comment: The "ciivil law" tag refers to civil law legal systems in contrast to common law legal systems, not to non-criminal legal matters.

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/402/government-legal-actions-civil-or-criminal?rq=1

Comment: Also, a nitpick, very few U.S. states have civil codes that are the main basis for a civil lawsuit (Louisiana and California would be notable exceptions). In almost all other U.S. states, the grounds for a civil lawsuit (e.g. car accidents, breach of contract) arise under common law case law and are not spelled out in a statutory civil code. Every U.S. state, however, has a statutory penal code (sometimes called a criminal code) spelling out most (but sometimes not all) crimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criminal prosecutions and civil actions can't both be commenced in the same case. This explanation focuses on English language common law terminology, but this bottom line is true in both common law legal systems and civil law legal systems. It is a basic structural foundation of both legal systems.

The term "criminal lawsuit" is non-standard. A "lawsuit" refers to a non-criminal civil action, usually commenced with a "complaint" but sometimes with a "petition" or a "motion" or even an "affidavit". Litigation seeking criminal penalties is called a "prosecution", which can be initiated with a "criminal complaint" or an "indictment" from a grand jury.

With some narrow and geographically restricted exceptions, criminal prosecutions can only be commenced by prosecutors, and non-prosecutors can only commence civil cases.

Even where private individuals can initiate criminal cases, criminal prosecutions and civil lawsuits can't be brought in the same complaint. Very different procedures apply to the different kind of cases. (A criminal contempt proceeding can be brought as a collateral part of a civil case when someone has violated a court order in that civil case, but one never files a complaint initially at the start of a civil lawsuit alleging criminal contempt.)

A civil case might reference a penal code provision, for example, in a [lawsuit seeking money damages for civil theft](https://law.justia.com/codes/colorado/2022/title-18/article-4/part-4/section-18-4-405/) or in a [negligence *per se*](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/negligence_per_se) claim. But then, the reference is not the basis of a criminal prosecution, it is just law relevant to civil liability and is stated among the facts in the civil complaint like any other fact or law relevant to the civil action. As explained at the link:

> Negligence *per se* means negligence in itself. In a tort case, a
> defendant who violates a statute or regulation without an excuse is
> automatically considered to have breached their duty of care and is
> therefore negligent as a matter of law. As a result, the only thing
> that must be proven at trial is whether the violation was the cause in
> fact and proximate cause of the plaintiff's injury. According to
> Restatement (Third) of Torts §14, an actor is negligent *per se* if
> they violate a statute that is designed to protect against the type of
> accident or harm caused by their conduct, and the plaintiff is someone
> the statute is designed to protect. Restatement (Third) of Torts §15
> lays out exceptions where an actor’s violation of a statute is excused
> and not considered negligent. The exceptions include cases where the
> statute is unclear, the actor exercised reasonable care in attempting
> to comply with the statute, or the actor’s noncompliance with the
> statute resulted in less harm than if they complied. The most common
> application of negligence per se is traffic violations, where the
> driver is automatically considered negligent for violating the traffic
> code.

Negligence *per se* doesn't need to be based upon a penal code statute violation, any statute or ordinance will do, but it is a not uncommon type of statute to support a negligence *per se* claim.

There are also some statutes which can be enforced both with criminal prosecutions and also with civil actions. In addition to theft, another important statute with that character is the federal Racketeering and Corrupt Organizations (RICO) statute, and parallel state statutes. These statutes involve criminal and civil claims arising out of organized crime activity, and require that a criminal organization (*de jure* or *de facto*) engaged in two or more predicate criminal acts, and in the case of a civil claim, that these acts caused harm to the people bringing the lawsuit.

Comment: Thanks. Can a criminal prosecution contain references to law relevant to civil liability? Also, if a lawsuit is filed by a lawyer, it is generally a civil lawsuit because lawyers are not prosecutors (unless they are district attorneys)?

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld "Can a criminal prosecution contain references to law relevant to civil liability?" Why would they do that? Criminal prosecutions only seek criminal liability (usually incarceration, fines, community service, probation, restitution). It might be mentioned to show motive, for example, however. "if a lawsuit is filed by a lawyer, it is generally a civil lawsuit because lawyers are not prosecutors (unless they are district attorneys)?" Yes. And, sometimes prosecutors file civil lawsuits on behalf of the government as well (see, e.g. the recent civil fraud case against Trump).

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld Honestly, I'm trying to figure out what kind of scenario you are getting at or what motivates your question. I have a hard time figuring out what assumptions or misconceptions are driving it.

Comment: I'm learning how to read a complaint, which contains cause of actions that refer to the penal and civil code.

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld Sounds like it is most likely a civil negligence *per se* claim in a civil lawsuit, but without more information, it is hard to know.